# How to get rounded value without fraction error when using numberFromString to generate NSDecimalNumber?

Tags: ios, number-formatting, nsdecimalnumber

I am trying to parse out a `NSDecimalNumber` from a String, but whatever attributes i set on numberFormatter, I can't get it to stop making a fraction error when getting `numberFromString`

```
let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
numberFormatter.decimalSeparator = "."
numberFormatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = true
numberFormatter.roundingMode = .RoundDown
numberFormatter.roundingIncrement = 0.01
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
let number = numberFormatter.numberFromString("93.9")
```

number gets set to 93.9000000000001, not 93.9. How can I get it to set the correct value for number?

Comment: how are you logging / observing this value ?

Comment: Both inspecting and in playground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a factory method defined on `NSDecimalNumber` that takes a string:

[+ (NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumberWithString:(NSString *)numericString](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDecimalNumber/decimalNumberWithString:)

Example:

```
$ swift
Welcome to Apple Swift version 2.1.1 (swiftlang-700.1.101.15 clang-700.1.81). Type :help for assistance.
  1> import Foundation
  2> NSDecimalNumber(string: "93.9")
$R0: NSDecimalNumber = 93.9
  3>
```

Comment: But this still gives you 93.09999999999999

Comment: I mean 93.90000000000001 for 93.9. The above comment was for 93.1

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last line with

```
let number = numberFormatter.numberFromString("93.7")?.floatValue
```

Comment: But then i won't get a NSDecimalNumber